# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereHas does not exist

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo para empezar una tabla `Sector`:

```
Schema::create('sectors', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

Esta tabla es utilizada en una tabla llamada `Experiencia`. No tienen relación formanea, pero el valor para `sector_empresa` se saca de la anterior tabla:

```
Schema::create('experiencias', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('puesto');
        $table->string('funcion_realizada');
        $table->string('empresa');
        $table->string('sector_empresa');
        $table->string('mes_anyo_inicio');
        $table->string('mes_anyo_fin');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Y esto se relaciona con los usuarios de la tabla:

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('second_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('provincia')->nullable();
        $table->string('localidad')->nullable();
        $table->string('direccion')->nullable();
        $table->string('telefono');
        $table->string('dni');
        $table->boolean('vehiculo')->default(false);
        $table->string('foto')->default('anonimo.jpg');
        $table->boolean('activado')->default(false); // Se marca aqui como falso y ya se pone automaticamente así al hacer el formulario.
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

La historia es que he creado una función para que se muestre, para un determinado sector, si un usuario tiene experiencia en eso:

```
public function fichaje(Sector $sector){
        $usuarios=User::all()->whereHas('experiencias',function($query){
            $query->where('sector_empresa',$sector->nombre);
        })->get();

        if(count($usuarios)==0)
            return back()->with('message',['danger','No hay ningun usuario interesado en este sector']);
        else
            return back()->with('message',['success','Hay usuarios interesados en este sector']);
    }
```

Pero al ejecutar el código me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué estaré haciendo mal?

Edito: He quitado el "all()" del condicional, dejando así el código:

```
public function fichaje(Sector $sector){
        $usuarios=User::whereHas('experiencias',function($query){
            $query->where('sector_empresa',$sector->nombre);
        })->get();

        if(count($usuarios)==0)
            return back()->with('message',['danger','No hay ningun usuario interesado en este sector']);
        else
            return back()->with('message',['success','Hay usuarios interesados en este sector']);
    }
```

Pero ahora me aparece un nuevo mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece ser que lo que hay en la función no capta las variables de fuera.

Comment: Veo que el `all()` esta sobrando, ese debe ser el error

Comment: Así he hecho, aunque ahora me encuentro con un nuevo problema. He editado para añadir más información.

Answer (score 1):

Ya he encontrado una solución.
Se le tiene que pasar las variables con la sentencia "use":

```
public function fichaje(Sector $sector){
        $usuarios=User::whereHas('experiencias',function($query) use ($sector){
            $query->where('sector_empresa',$sector->nombre);
        })->get();

        if(count($usuarios)==0)
            return back()->with('message',['danger','No hay ningun usuario interesado en este sector']);
        else
            return back()->with('message',['success','Hay usuarios interesados en este sector']);
    }
```